# How to get all values from complex multi-dimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have the following multi-dimensional array

```html
$sample = array(
        '1232' => 'Nokia 72',
        '234' => array(
                    '534' => 'Samsung 58',
                    '345' => 'Samsung 64'
                  ),
        '3445' => 'Micromax 1542c',
        '542' => array(
                    '4645' => 'LG 58',
                    '5765' => 'LG 64'
                  )
      );
```

Now, I want to collect only values of every values of each section.

My output should be like below

```html
 
 Array 
 ( 
  [0] => Nokia 72
  [1] => Samsung 58
  [2] => Samsung 64
  [3] => Micromax 1542c
  [4] => LG 58
  [5] => LG 64
 )
```

I don't want to do it with foreach function.

Comment: And what you have tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by using

```html
array_walk_recursive($sample, create_function('$val, $key, $obj', 'array_push($obj, $val);'), &output);
```

You can also get some more reference from below link

[How-to-filter-only-values-from-complex-multi-dimensional-array](http://questionnanswer.com/questions/view_question/138/category_list:2/How-to-filter-only-values-from-complex-multi-dimensional-array?)

Comment: Some explanation of what you did here would be nice.

Answer (score 2):

```
$sample = array(
        '1232' => 'Nokia 72',
        '234' => array(
                    '534' => 'Samsung 58',
                    '345' => 'Samsung 64'
                  ),
        '3445' => 'Micromax 1542c',
        '542' => array(
                    '4645' => 'LG 58',
                    '5765' => 'LG 64'
                  )
      );

array_walk_recursive($sample, function($a) use (&$return) { $return[] = $a; });

var_dump($return);
```

Output:

```
array(6) { [0]=> string(8) "Nokia 72" [1]=> string(10) "Samsung 58" [2]=> string(10) "Samsung 64" [3]=> string(14) "Micromax 1542c" [4]=> string(5) "LG 58" [5]=> string(5) "LG 64" }
```

Here is a PHP Sandbox with the demo: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/

This solution uses array_walk_recursive() and PHP anonymous functions.

http://php.net/array_walk_recursive

http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php

Answer (score 1):

[**`RecursiveIteratorIterator`**](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursiveiteratoriterator.php) 
it returns a flattened array when you used with `iterator_to_array` function.

[**`Demo`**](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c698f891c0e1ce2cfde8890c032e7b1929db227c)

```
$sample = array(
        '1232' => 'Nokia 72',
        '234' => array(
                    '534' => 'Samsung 58',
                    '345' => 'Samsung 64'
                  ),
        '3445' => 'Micromax 1542c',
        '542' => array(
                    '4645' => 'LG 58',
                    '5765' => 'LG 64'
                  )
      );

$it =  new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($sample));
$l = iterator_to_array($it, false);
echo '<pre>';print_r($l);echo '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to implement it on your own with a recursive function:

```
$sample = array(
        '1232' => 'Nokia 72',
        '234' => array(
            '534' => 'Samsung 58',
            '345' => 'Samsung 64'
            ),
        '3445' => 'Micromax 1542c',
        '542' => array(
            '4645' => 'LG 58',
            '5765' => 'LG 64'
            )
        );

// This recursive function changes the original values!
function walk(&$multi_dim_array, &$flat_array)
{
    while (sizeof($multi_dim_array) > 0)
    {
        // Take the first element
        $curr_value = array_shift($multi_dim_array);
        // If this item is an array go one step deeper
        if (is_array($curr_value))
            walk($curr_value, $flat_array);
        else
            // The current value is not an array
            // append it to the flattened array
            $flat_array[] = $curr_value;
    }
}

$values = [];
walk($sample, $values);
print_r($values);
```

Outputs

```
Array ( [0] => Nokia 72 [1] => Samsung 58 [2] => Samsung 64 [3] => Micromax 1542c [4] => LG 58 [5] => LG 64 )
```